# Taking a long time to close fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

Why is my fstream taking 30+ seconds to close after writing data to the file? The more I write, the longer it takes to close.

```
fstream *writeReadStream = new fstream("/media/username/KODAK/file.bin", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::binary);
writeReadStream->seekg(0x100000);
char randomData[0x100000];

for (int i = 0; i < 0x270; i++)
    writeReadStream->write(randomData, 0x100000);

writeReadStream->close();
delete writeReadStream;
```

When debugging, I see that the application hangs on the `close` call. Even when not debugging and calling `printf`'s before and after the `close` call, it will take a long time to reach the second `printf`. Again, the more I write the longer it takes. Any idea why?

This only seems to happen on flash drives/SD cards.

Comment: `fstream *writeReadStream = new fstream...` This heap allocation is completely unnecessary here, given that you delete it in the same scope.

Comment: That array is a nice way to use your whole stack.

Comment: I just decided to keep it like this because where I am actually having the problem I have it on the heap.

Comment: @hetelek, `std::string` not working?

Comment: @hetelek: Keeping silly code around is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The writes were likely buffered.  The close is causing it to flush, so you must wait for it to be written to disk first.  Try putting a flush in your for loop and then see if the close takes a long time or not.

```
fstream *writeReadStream = new fstream("/home/username/Desktop/file.bin", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::binary);
writeReadStream->seekg(0x100000);
char randomData[0x100000];

for (int i = 0; i < 0x270; i++)
{
    writeReadStream->write(randomData, 0x100000);
    writeReadStream->flush();
}

writeReadStream->close();
delete writeReadStream;
```

Comment: Flushing it still makes it hang for while on the `close` call.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing a fair amount of data.  Your problem might be due to buffering.  I would try the unbuffered C api if I were you:

```
FILE *fd = std::fopen("/home/username/Desktop/file.bin", "w");
if (!fd) {
   // handle error
}
std::setvbuf(fd, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

if (0 != std::fseek(fd, 0x100000, SEEK_SET)) {
    // handle error
}
for (int i = 0; i < 0x270; i++) {
    if (1 != std::fwrite(randomData, 0x100000, 1, fd)) {
         // handle error
    }
}

close(fd);
```

See if it is faster

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not speed it up.

Comment: @helelek does it still block on the close()?  For how much time?

Comment: @hetelek then I'd look how the filesystem is mounted.  It should not have to flush the page cache on close().

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that it's faster to open-append/write/close the file on each loop iteration, than opening once before and closing once after the loop.  Somehow each close performs the flush we'd expect, but flush() does not.